# Speed up symbolic claculation with mathematica

Tags: performance, wolfram-mathematica

I have wirtten the following code. It is a code for mathematica and I would like to do some "simple" linear algebra with symbols. 
The code sets up a matrix (called A) and a vector (called b). Then it solves the euqation A*k=b for k.
Unfortunately, my code is super slow, e.g. for n=5 it takes hours.
Is there any better way for solving this problem? I am not that familiar with mathematica and my code is rather unprofessional, so do you have any hints for speeding things up?
Here is my code.

```
clear[all];


n = 3;

MM = Table[Symbol["M" <> ToString@i], {i, 1, n}];

RB = Table[
   Symbol["RA" <> FromCharacterCode[65 + i] <> ToString@(i + 1)], {i, 
    1, n - 1}];

mA = Table[Symbol["mA" <> FromCharacterCode[65 + i]], {i, 1, n - 1}];
mX = Table[
   Symbol["m" <> FromCharacterCode[65 + i] <> "A"], {i, 1, n - 1}];
R = Table[
   Symbol["R" <> FromCharacterCode[64 + i] <> ToString@(j + 1)], {i, 
    1, n}, {j, 1, n - 1}];




b = Table[-MM[[1]]*(1/(mA[[i]]*(R[[1, i]] - RB[[i]])) - 
      1/(mX[[i]]*(-R[[i + 1, i]] + RB[[i]]))), {i, 1, n - 1}];



A = Table[
   MM[[j + 1]]*(R[[1, j]]/(mA[[i]]*(R[[1, i]] - RB[[i]])) - 
      R[[i + 1, j]]/(mX[[i]]*(-R[[i + 1, i]] + RB[[i]]))), {i, 1, 
    n - 1}, {j, 1, n - 1}];


K = LinearSolve[A, b];
MatrixForm[K]
```

Thanks for any hints!

P.S. The code should run!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. On my 2018 MacBook Pro the `n = 5` case completes in under 20s. The result is a very large expression with a `LeafCount` of 22039. What is `clear[all]` in your code? Is it a function you wrote that is equivalent to ClearAll["Global``*"]

Comment: Clear[all] is an on board function.. I had some trouble with variables if I run the code several times in a row

Comment: `Clear[all]` will only clear the values and definitions of the specific symbol `all`. It will not clear attributes, defaults or messages associated with the symbol. You should use `ClearAll["Global``*"]`. See the [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clear.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of variables and lots of denominators, both of which can often make things very slow.

Let's try a simpler faster method that solves a generic form of your problem and then substitutes in all your variables and denominators.

```
n = 5;
MM = ...
...
A = ...
m={{m1,m2,m3,m4},{m5,m6,m7,m8},{m9,m10,m11,m12},{m13,m14,m15,m16}};
sol=Inverse[m].b/.Thread[Rule[Flatten[m],Flatten[A]]]
```

which gives a solution in fraction of a second. But you need to carefully check this to justify that there are no zero denominators hiding in your problem or this solution.

This method is faster than `Inverse[A].b` and far faster than `LinearSolve[A, b]` for your problem, but that time is only for the calculation of the solution and does not include any potentially large amount of time spent using the solution. It also does not include any of the programming hidden inside `LinearSolve` to deal with potential problems and special cases.

But I am not certain as your n grows larger and your forest of denominators grows far larger that this will continue to be fast or feasible.

Test this carefully before you assume everything works.

P.S. Thank you for the code that actually ran! (I didn't even use the clear[all])

Comment: OK I will try this. Thank you! Actually I also wanted to use Simplfy[K] also to make my result more handy but it turned out that even solving was very time consuming.

Comment: Mathematica doesn't really have "intuition", it can't look at the solution, see that all the terms have the same structure, see that there appear to only be two general forms that structure could be put into, either over a single denominator or separate fractions added together, and thus quickly tell you there are not great simplifications. Instead it grinds away for vast amounts of time and gives you a result about the same size and complexity as you had. With Mathematica people pose problems that can take vast amounts of time and only possibly return an answer. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Hey Bill I just realized that your code is not exactly what I need. In your code m is not dynamic

Comment: Yes I understood that m was not dynamic. From your original code it appeared that you understood how to use `Table` and `Symbol` and `ToString` to construct symbol names. So I expected you would be able to see how to adapt my simple example to your actual problem. I try to clearly and simply provide just the key bits that a person asking the question doesn't know how to do.